# Defining a pointer to a struct gives me not declared in this scope error

Tags: c

So I define a structure

```
struct PAIR{
    int a;
    int b;
    int dist;
};
```

and after this in a function I try to define Pair * vec; and it gives me

```
optim.cpp:97:4: error: ‘Pair’ was not declared in this scope
optim.cpp:97:10: error: ‘vec’ was not declared in this scope
```

What's the problem?

Comment: It's `PAIR`, screaming, not `Pair`, talking.

Comment: @Als I was going to say that, too. But then I noticed the filename was `*.cpp`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: The Q is tagged C

Comment: @Als Yes, the OP should clarify.

Comment: So, what's correct, the filename or the tag?

Answer (score 2):

C is case sensitive, So you should use PAIR instead of Pair.

I am not sure which compiler you use, gcc or g++? If you use g++ (as the file you show is optim.cpp), I think you can fix your problem if you just correct Pair to PAIR. If you use gcc, then your should add the **struct** prefix to the structure.

Answer (score 1):

c is case sensitve. PAIR and Pair are not the same.

Moreover, struct PAIR is not automatically typedef.

You need to declare a variable/pointer as

```
struct PAIR * instance;
```

Or you need to typedef it first like

```
typedef struct PAIR
{
     // variables;
} Pair; // note the typedef name appears at the end.
```

Now you can do like this

```
Pair var;
```

In c++ a type is automatically typedef, but not in c

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
struct PAIR *ve;
```

instead.